# Which single-board computer can I use elementary OS with?

Tags: hardware

I'm looking for a cheap board like Raspberry Pi (which sadly, is not compatible with elementary OS) that is powerful enough to use elementary OS, play 1080p 60hz videos and movies without a lag, and surf the web properly. I will not play any games or do anything else except for these. So, I don't want to build an expensive PC. I've been searching for a board for a while but am unable to find one that is capable of running elementary OS. I'd appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: elementaryOS only makes 64bit images, so no ARM or x86 support, just so you know..

Comment: Is there any info if Juno will support ARM and x86? And when will it be released?

Comment: I don't think so - x86 was supported before but has been dropped due to high maintenance / low user base. About ARM, elementaryOS explicitly focuses on the desktop experience and has no plans to go mobile, afaik, so I don't think they are gonna support mobile processors like ARM. Ubuntu however supports both, so you can look at some of its flavours.

Answer (score 2):

In short - any 64bit board that's supported by Ubuntu.